# Why is my overridden Dispose not called?

Tags: c#, .net, compact-framework, overriding, dispose

I'm currently working with the TextWriter class from .NET Compact Framework 3.5 to write log entries to a file. Thats a very common and simply task and there is no problem with that. But using the TextWriter and calling Dispose when all data has been written causes the file kept open.

My approach was to initialize a FileStream, then a StreamWriter using the created instance of the FileStream. Then i created a synchronized TextWriter using the static method Synchronized.

To investigate why my the file is not accessible by another process after the data has been written and flushed i derived a class from StreamWriter with an override of the Dispose method just to see if it is called. Running the code showed up the overriden Dispose method is not called and thats what confuses me.

The calling code is:

```
var fileStream = new FileStream("\\NAND_FLASH\\test.file", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
var streamWriter = new ExtendedWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8);

TextWriter textWriter = TextWriter.Synchronized(streamWriter);
textWriter.Dispose();
```

And the derived class:

```
internal class ExtendedWriter : StreamWriter
{
    public ExtendedWriter(Stream stream) : base(stream)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding) : base(stream, encoding)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(Stream stream, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) : base(stream, encoding, bufferSize)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(string path) : base(path)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(string path, bool append) : base(path, append)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding) : base(path, append, encoding)
    {
    }

    public ExtendedWriter(string path, bool append, Encoding encoding, int bufferSize) : base(path, append, encoding, bufferSize)
    {
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Extended writer dispose!");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

Can someone explain this behavior to me?

**Edit:**
Updated question text, i missed to mention that i am working with the .NET Compact Framework 3.5

Comment: It works for me with the code you've provided. Are you sure it's not just a matter of your tracing failing?

Comment: Indeed, you are right, under the full framework 3.5 the code will run as expected. I missed to test that yesterday. My initial test based on the .net compact framework 3.5 (what i have forgotten to mention). There the dispose method of the ExtendedWriter is not called.

Comment: Hmm. That sounds highly unusual to me - but I can't easily test it for myself, unfortunately :(

Comment: Maybe i have missed something but after reviewing my code which is the same for both platforms (using the same files in two projects) i can't find anything that explains why it behaves like that.

Comment: Are you sure you do not need to dispose of your FileStream? I know some wrapped Stream interfaces say they Close/Dispose of the underlying stream (And some, for example XMLStreams you can specify the behavior), but I didn't read anything in those methods that said they would dispose of the stream that you created it from. I would try making sure I called FileStream.Dispose() after you dispose of your TextWriter

Comment: Sure i can Close/Dispose the other underlying stream by myself, but that's not the question. I'm wondering why my overwritten dispose is never called which should work equal to the full .net framework. And is a fundamental mechanic of derivation of classes/objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just used Reflector to look at the TextWriter in the CF 3.5 BCL.

Here's the Dispose, which you're calling:

```
public void Dispose()
{
    this.Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

So this is calling the parameterized Dispose, which looks like this:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
}
```

So there's the explanation as to why your derived StreamWriter isn't getting Disposed - the TextWriter doesn't call Dispose on its contained StreamWriter.  You'll have to Dispose your object yourself.

Comment: Indeed that makes sense, sad that this difference exists between the two frameworks. Thank you for looking for the explanation.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem.  TextWriter itself doesn't have any resources: the Dispose() body is likewise empty in the full framework.  TextWriter.Synchronized(TextWriter) creates a SyncTextWriter, which does dispose its argument.  StreamWriter likewise overrides Dispose to close its stream.

Comment: Nope.  I just verified again.  TextWriter.Synchronized in the CF does create a SyncTextWriter, but it has no Dispose implementation, so it inherits the implementation from its base, the TextWriter, which has the implementations in the answer.  It's definitely a CF 3.5 (and likely 2.0 and maybe 3.9) bug.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think everything does what it is supposed to whenever it implements the `IDisposable` interface.

For example, using a Microsoft Access database connection (OleDb) will never close the connection if you open it in a `using` clause.

My guess is this you found another control that does not do everything it is supposed to do.